# UIPageViewController throws SIGABRT on orientation change

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt, uipageviewcontroller

I have the following code to display a magazine type app. When the app is rotated it runs this code. I made sure that it is only run when rotated to supported orientations. When this function returns, the app fails with a SIGABRT. There is no other indication as to why.

I know it's this function because when I remove it the program does not fail.

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
                   spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    //If portrait mode, change to single page view
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
        UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
         NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
         [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

         self.pageViewController.doubleSided = NO;

        return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
    //If landscape mode, change to double page view    
    }else{
        //Get current view 
        UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

        //Create an array to store, views
        NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

         NSUInteger currentIndex = self.currentPage;

        //Conditional to check if needs page before or after
         if(currentIndex == 1 || currentIndex %2 == 1){
             UIViewController *nextViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:currentViewController];
             viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentViewController,nextViewController, nil];
         }else{
             UIViewController *previousViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:currentViewController];
             viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousViewController, currentViewController, nil];
         }

        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;

    }
    //return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}
```

Comment: I upgraded to SDK5.1 and now I get this in the console:
_Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'All provided view controllers ((
    "<UIViewController: 0x68648b0>",
    "<UIViewController: 0x6aaa080>"
)) must support the pending interface orientation (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)'_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you didn't provide the output from the console, which would be nice.  Giving the code a quick look I would guess that one of your controllers (next or previous) is nil, and since you can't insert nil into an NSArray (except as the last object) it is throwing an error.

**EDIT** Well, my guess was wrong.  The error message is saying that the UIViewControllers you are giving to it do not support the orientation that the page controller needs.  This is because you have a method called `shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your child UIViewControllers, and they are returning no for (in this case) left landscape.

Comment: I added console output, which i get now that I've upgraded SDK's

Comment: @RyanH See my updated answer, and in the future try to always include info like this.  SIGABRT by itself tells us nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, borrrden is probably right. One of your IBOutlets is probably missing from your XIB. Make sure ALL of your IBs are connected properly, and if the problem continues, say so.

Comment: Thanks, but my file is made programmatically not using a nib.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'All provided view controllers ((
    "<ContentViewController: 0x6a7eac0>",
    "<ContentViewController: 0x6d89f10>"
)) must support the pending interface orientation (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)'
```

Adding the following to my PageModel class, where the page layout is designed worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```